# Python code checker for comparing a function as an attribute

Tags: python, static-analysis, lint

I occasionally spend a considerable amount of time tracking down brainfarts in my code... while I normally run pylint against it, there are some things that slip past pylint.  The easiest problem for me to overlook is this...

```
# normally, variable is populated from parsed text, so it's not predictable
variable = 'fOoBaR'
if variable.lower == 'foobar':
    #       ^^^^^<------------------ should be .lower()
    do_something()
```

Neither pylint nor Python bark about this... is there a python code-checking tool that can flag this particular issue?

Comment: Unit testing would resolve this. I've never been incredibly impressed by pylint or pychecker, to be fair, 'linting' a language like python is a hard problem.

Comment: Indeed, unit testing is how I know something is broken... the issue is finding where it broke.

Comment: @Mike Pennington I don't understand what is the issue. What does it mean : _should be .lower()_ ?

Comment: @Mike sounds like you need more coverage in your unit tests. Say you think you're testing a method that returns a string, but you're getting a bound method? You should have something to test for that.

Comment: @eyq: Its a human error. Should be the builtin `lower()` and mike wants to guard against these errors.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I'm evaluating the value in variable against a constant.  In this case, variable is populated from parsed text

Comment: I think the easiest way to avoid this sort of mistakes is to use an IDE, but since I myself use vim to write my python I'm open to IDE suggestions:)

Comment: I use vim with [python.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790)

Comment: @t.dubrownik Which python IDE do you think checks for this kind of thing? Komodo, pyscripter, and Eclipse don't seem to... Can you fill me in or are you just guessing?

Comment: @marr75 Eclipse doesn't detect this in code (and it can't, I mean it isn't an error in the general case) but it could conceivably save you from making the mistake in the first place - I just pulled up my Eclipse installation (3.6.1 + PyDev 1.6.1) and when I tried typing the example I got a completion popup which showed me .lower(). That said I still had to either hit enter to accept or write the '(' myself.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to methods on built-in datatypes, or the construct a.b in general? (1) a.b could be a legitimate reference to a module or class variable; though one might want a checker to insist that variables other than an instance's own be accessed only through functions, not all code - even Python's - adheres to this rule. (2) b might be a @property method, in which case a.b is in fact a method call, not a method; this ambiguity might discourage some people from using that feature, but others like it. It is not the role of a code checker to legislate against either case.

Comment: @MitchellModel, code checkers specialize in this task; even if b is a property, the code checker can introspect b to understand whether this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [pylint ticket #65910](http://www.logilab.org/ticket/65910)

Answer (score 0):

@Mike Pennington I just want to first say that I also run into this a lot -.-

@eyquem 'lower()' is a function. 'lower' is a function pointer (if I'm not mistaken). Python will let you attempt to run this code, but it will not invoke the function.

I think the reason this is hard to catch is that you don't always know the type of the variable which you're calling methods on. For example, say I have 2 classes.

```
class Foo()
   def func(self):
      #do stuff
      pass

class Bar()
   self.func = "stuff"
```

If your code has a function in it that takes an argument 'baz' like so:

```
def myfunction(baz):
    print baz.func

def myfunction(baz):
    baz.func()
```

Either one of these could be valid depending on baz's type.
There is literally no way of knowing if baz is of type 'Foo' or 'Bar', though.

EDIT: I meant with static analysis...

Comment: There is absolutely a way to know types. `type(obj)`; `isinstance(obj, (cls1, cls2))`, `issubclass(obj, cls)`...

Answer (score 0):

How do you propose a code-checker validate this?  It's perfectly legitimate syntax. Rather than checking for this kind of mistake, it would be better to get into the habit of using better patterns.

Instead of:

```
variable = 'fOoBaR'
if variable.lower == 'foobar':
    #       ^^^^^<------------------ should be .lower()
    do_something()
```

Do this:

```
variable = 'fOoBaR'
sane_variable = variable.lower()
if sane_variable == 'foobar':
    do_something()
```

This way you're always explicitly calling `.lower()` on the value you're comparing against, instead of relying on an in-place method-call and comparison, which leads to the very pitfall you're experiencing.

Comment: did you read the enhancement I filed with pylint?  I explained very clearly what I am looking for.  There is no good reason I can think of to compare a function pointer to a constant value... it is nonsense.